# (412) A lease ID was specified, but the lease for the blob has expired

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

My event processor sometimes receive exception when checkpointing:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> >Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException: Exception of type >'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.LeaseLostException' was thrown. ---> >Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an >error: (412) A lease ID was specified, but the lease for the blob has expired.. ->--> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (412) A lease >ID was specified, but the lease for the blob has expired.

Can I renew lease just before checkpoiting in ProcessEventsAsync method?
Or how can I manage PartitionManagerOptions to make this work?

Code:

```
public virtual Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    //some processing
    context.CheckpointAsync().Wait();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure that StackTrace indicates the exception occurred when calling CheckpointAsync.  Or are you saying you saw that behavior in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the `EPH` (EventProcessorHost) whenever, `EPH` loadbalances `EventHubs` partitions across '`EPH` instances and is harmless if you see it once in a while (aka less frequently).

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867611/3277385) for detailed explanation on Lease Management.