# What is causing Azure Event Hubs ReceiverDisconnectedException/LeaseLostException?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm receiving events from an EventHub using EventProcessorHost and an IEventProcessor class (call it: MyEventProcessor).  I scale this out to two servers by running my EPH on both servers, and having them connect to the Hub using the same ConsumerGroup, but unique hostName's (using the machine name).

The problem is: at random hours of the day/night, the app logs this:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: ReceiverDisconnectedException 
Exception message: New receiver with higher epoch of '186' is created hence current receiver with epoch '186' is getting disconnected. If you are recreating the receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used.
  at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)
  at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.Parallel.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

This Exception occurs at the same time as a LeaseLostException, thrown from MyEventProcessor's CloseAsync method when it tries to checkpoint.  (Presumably Close is being called because of the ReceiverDisconnectedException?)

I think this is occurring due to Event Hubs' automatic lease management when scaling out to multiple machines.  But I'm wondering if I need to do something different to make it work more cleanly and avoid these Exceptions? Eg: something with epochs?

Comment: may be helpful https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f89ade2f-c695-42e6-944b-6a744f081f90/is-there-a-recommanded-way-to-handle-microsoftservicebusmessagingreceiverdisconnectedexception?forum=servbus

Comment: Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27832015/1658906 ?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov thanks, my goal in posting here is to see if "yes, ignore it" is an answer that gets posted and receives several up-votes from the community.  To answer that poster's follow-up question of frequency: my exceptions are happening sometimes 5 in 1 hour, but then it may skip a few hours before it occurs again.  These 5 occurrences may be for different Partitions I guess, I noticed that I'm not logging on which partitionId the Exception occurred.

Comment: @juunas thanks, using two consumer groups isn't the answer for me, as separate consumer groups should be used when you have to read the data for multiple purposes, ie: to go and do different things with it.  In my case, I'm reading the data for one purpose, but scaling that out to multiple machines (which that link also describes, but I think i'm doing it exactly as they and MS recommended).  I'm just not clear on why running my EPH on multiple machines (or Worker Roles) leads to thrown Exceptions. None of their docs say to expect that.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**TLDR**: This behavior is absolutely normal.

**Why can't Lease Management be smooth & exception-free**: To give more control on the situation to developer.

**The really long story - all-the-way from Basics**
`EventProcessorhost` (hereby `EPH` - is very similar to what `__consumer_offset topic` does for `Kafka Consumers` - partition ownership & checkpoint store) is written by `Microsoft Azure EventHubs` team themselves - to translate all of the `EventHubs partition receiver Gu` into a simple `onReceive(Events)` callback.

`EPH` is used to address 2 general, major, well-known problems while reading out of a high-throughput partitioned streams like `EventHubs`:

1. **fault tolerant receive pipe-line** - for ex: a simpler version of the problem - if the host running a `PartitionReceiver` dies and comes back - it needs to resume processing from where it left. To remember the last successfully processed `EventData`, `EPH` uses the `blob` supplied to `EPH` constructor to store the checkpoints - when ever user invokes `context.CheckpointAsync()`. Eventually, when the host process dies (for ex: abruptly reboots or hits a hardware fault and never/comesback) - any `EPH` instance can pick up this task and resume from that `Checkpoint`.
2. **Balance/distribute partitions across `EPH` instances** - lets say, if there are 10 partitions and 2 `EPH` instances processing events from these 10 partitions - we need a way to divide partitions across the instances (`PartitionManager` component of `EPH` library does this). We use **`Azure Storage - Blob LeaseManagement-feature`**  to implement this. As of version [`2.2.10`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost) - to simplify the problem, `EPH` assumes that **all partitions are loaded equally**.

With this, lets try to see what's going on:
So, to start with, in the above example of `10` event hub partitions and `2` `EPH` instances processing events out of them:

1. lets say the first `EPH` instance - `EPH1` started, at-first, alone and a part of start-up, it created receivers to all 10 partitions and is processing events. In the start up - `EPH1` will announce that it owns all these `10` partitions by acquiring Leases on `10` storage blobs representing these `10` event hub partitions (with a standard `nomenclature`- which `EPH` internally creates in the Storage account - from the `StorageConnectionString` passed to the `ctor`). Leases will be [acquired for a set time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitionmanageroptions#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_PartitionManagerOptions_LeaseInterval), after which the `EPH` instance will loose the ownership on this Partition.
2. `EPH1` continually `announces` once in a while - that it is still owning those partitions - by `renewing` leases on the blob. Frequency of `renewal`, along with other useful tuning, can be performed using [`PartitionManagerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitionmanageroptions)
3. now, lets say, `EPH2` starts up - and you supplied the same `AzureStorageAccount` as `EPH1` to the `ctor` of `EPH2` as well. Right now, it has `0` partitions to process. So, to achieve balance of partitions across `EPH` instances, it will go ahead and `download` the list of all `leaseblobs` which has the mapping of `owner` to `partitionId`. From this, **it will `STEAL` leases** for its fair share of `partitions` - which is `5` in our example, and will announce that information on that `lease blob`. As part of this, `EPH2` reads the latest checkpoint written by `PartitionX` it wants to steal the lease for and goes ahead and creates corresponding `PartitionReceiver`'s with the `EPOCH` same as the one in the `Checkpoint`.
4. As a result, `EPH1` will loose ownership of these 5 `partitions` and will run into different errors based on the exact state it is in.

   - if `EPH1` is actually invoking the `PartitionReceiver.Receive()` call - while `EPH2` is creating the `PartitionReceiver` on the same receiver - `EPH1` will experience [ReceiverDisconnectedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.receiverdisconnectedexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoft_servicebus_messaging_receiverdisconnectedexception#constructors_summary). This will eventually, invoke `IEventProcessor.Close(CloseReason=LeaseLost)`. Note that, probability of hitting this specific Exception is higher, if the messages being received are larger or the `PrefetchCount` is smaller - as in both cases the receiver would be performing more aggressive I/O.
   - if `EPH1` is in the state of `checkpointing` the `lease` or `renewing` the `lease`, while the `EPH2` `stole` the lease, the `EventProcessorOptions.ExceptionReceived` eventHandler would be signaled with a `leaselostException` (with `409` conflict error on the `leaseblob`) - which also eventually invokes `IEventProcess.Close(LeaseLost)`.

**Why can't Lease Management be smooth & exception-free**:

To keep the consumer simple and error-free, lease management related exceptions could have been swallowed by `EPH` and not notified to the user-code at all. However, we realized, throwing `LeaseLostException` could empower customers to find interesting bugs in `IEventProcessor.ProcessEvents()` callback - for which the symptom would be - frequent partition-moves

- minor network outage on a specific machine - due to which `EPH1` fails to `renew` leases and comes back up! - and imagine if the n/w of this machine stands flaky for a day - `EPH` instances are going to play `ping-pong` with `Partitions`! This machine will continuously try to steal the lease from other machine - which is legitimate from `EPH` point-of-view - but, is a total disaster for the user of `EPH` - as it completely interferes with the processing pipe. `EPH` - would exactly see a `ReceiverDisconnectedException`, when the n/w comes back up on this flaky m/c! We think the best and infact the only way is to enable the developer to smell this!
- or a simple scenario like, having a bug in `ProcessEvents` logic - which throws unhandled exceptions which are fatal and brings down the whole process - ex: a poison event. This partition is going to move around a lot.
- customers, performing write/delete operations on the same storage account which `EPH` is also using - by mistake (like an automated clean-up script) etc.
- last but not the least - which we never wish could happen - say a 5 min `outage` on Azure d.c where a specific `EventHub.Partition` is located - say n/w incident. Partitions are going to move around across `EPH` instances.

Basically, in majority of situations, it would be tricky - for us to detect the diff. between these situations and a legitimate leaseLost due to balancing and we want to delegate control of these situations to the Developer.

[more on Event Hubs...](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I really appreciate it. One more small question on PartitionManagerOptions: would you say that the value I use for LeaseInterval should always be greater than the message processing time I expect, to avoid partitions bouncing between EPH's without ever finishing processing a message? Eg: I have one EventHub whose messages are processed by making several calls to Table Storage. For one message on this hub, processing time could take 1 minute, so is it critical that I use a LeaseInterval more than 1 minute when I have 2 EPH's running on this EventHub?

Comment: @plukich - partitionManagerOptions.LeaseInterval and RenewInterval determines the lease renewal times. Lease renewal doesn't depend on the time taken by ProcessEventsAsync call.

Comment: @Sreeram would it be a good solution to resend events to EventHub using EventHubClient and then get it again?

Comment: Isn't this some kind of 'misuse' of exceptions ?  An exception is being thrown to control flow, instead of indicating that an unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: I am a kafka user and tried to move on azure eventhub. Azure eventhub is not fast and reliable as compared to kafka. There were lots of connection loss and msg exception. Code on driver level in not production ready.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a Local instance the Function App running on my laptop and another in cloud. Both with same trigger configuration (same EH, same consumer).